# How can I identify which record has the MAX for a particular field?

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

The title is pretty much self explanatory. I want to find out a way to identify which record the MAX of a field is in.

Comment: Greetings, could you let us know what you have tried?

Comment: this is quite broad. not sure  what exactly you need . look up max sql and bam

Comment: I don't see a problem with the question. Using `MAX` to get the answer is actually the long way around.

Comment: I want to access the data in the "Forename" and "Surname" field from the record that has the max in the "Goals" field. Not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with MySQL or Postgres:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyField DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or this with MSSQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyField DESC
```

Oracle requires a nested SELECT with ROWNUM:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyField DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: The first sql statement will work wonders, it pretty much solves all the issues I've been having. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the DBMS that you're using. @StilesCrisis covered MySQL and MSSQL; in Oracle you might do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY myfield DESC
) WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Postgres uses the same syntax as MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY myfield DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I've incorporated the Oracle query to avoid splitting the answer up into multiple places. (Kicking myself too, I use Oracle at work every day. But the question is tagged VB.NET so I just assume MSSQL.)